# SharePoint Survey, Ask n times based on answer 

Tags: sharepoint, survey

We need to implement a survey which will allow the following:

- Question 1: How many cars do you own?
- Answer: Dropdown (Values range from 1 - 5)

Based on the answer to this question, we need the same set of questions asked 5 times.
For example, what is the colour and make of your car...and so on.

Is there a way to achieve this with SharePoint using the OOB features/InfoPath forms?

Answer (score 1):

To be OOTB, I see two options: InfoPath (ideally Forms Services if you have MOSS Enterprise) or a Survey list.  The InfoPath solution will be much nicer, but take a little longer to set up (maybe a couple of hours vs 30 minutes).  Also, if you don't have MOSS Enterprise then you can't use InfoPath Forms Services and everyone has to have the InfoPath client installed on their desktop.

For InfoPath, this is just designing the form with the needed logic. You won't need any code behind.  I would simply have your initial question, then have a section for each subsequent set of questions.  In the display tab of the sections you can have conditional logic to hide the section based on the answer to the first question.  All of your answers can be promoted to SharePoint form library fields if you desire.

I think the Survey list will be a little more of a kludge (technical term).  It has limited branching logic capability so it might work a little odd.  In the Survey you can branch to another question based on the answer for that question.  So, you could order your questions as such (basically backwards):

1. How many cars do you own?
   (if 4 branch to question #4, if 3 branch to question #6, if 2 branch to #8, if 1 branch to #10)
2. Car #5 question #1
3. Car #5 question #2
4. Car #4 question #1
5. Car #4 question #2
6. Car #3 question #1
7. Car #3 question #2
8. Car #2 question #1
9. Car #2 question #2
10. Car #1 question #1
11. Car #1 question #2

Maybe someone else can come up with a better solution with the Survey list?